# Signal Not coming though - PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am sending a signal from another class to update a PySide QTableWidget but nothing is coming though. I have made this very simple for this demonstration:

This is in the controller module called `Records.py`

```
class Records(QDialog, randomDialog.Ui_watchingDialog):

    signal = 1
    atSig = Signal(int)

    def add_button_clicked(self):

        # Do some stuff
        self.signal = 1
        self.atSig.emit(self.signal)
        # Do some other Stuff
```

This sits out side the controller called `main.py`

```
from controller import Records

class main(QMainWindow, pyMainWindow.Ui_mainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        signal_records = Records.Records()

        signal_records.atSig.connect(self.showNewData)


    def showNewData(self, signal):
        if signal == 1:
            print "It worked!"
        else:
            print "Problem"
```

How come this signal is not coming through? No error messages are being thrown and neither of the print statements aren't being called. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are your sure ' def add_button_clicked(self):' have call. I work with my pyqt4, It work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If It's possibly, please define this before caller to receive;

```
.
.
@Slot (int)
def showNewData(self, signal):
.
.
```

Or it not, Please check your caller `def add_button_clicked(self)`. I work in pyqt4 (same pySide) and (I cut some part out and put some path for test in your) code, It's work.

```
import sys  
from PyQt4 import QtCore  
from PyQt4 import QtGui  

class QRecordsDialog (QtGui.QDialog):
    addButtonClickedSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QRecordsDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Test Signal', self)
        self.myQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.myQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQPushButton)
        self.setLayout(self.myQHBoxLayout)
        self.myQPushButton.clicked.connect(self.addButtonClicked)

    def addButtonClicked (self):
        self.addButtonClickedSignal.emit(1)

class QMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        myQRecordsDialog = QRecordsDialog(self)
        myQRecordsDialog.addButtonClickedSignal.connect(self.showNewData)
        myQRecordsDialog.show()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def showNewData (self, signal):
        if signal == 1:
            print "It worked !"
        else:
            print "Problem ?"

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQMainWindow = QMainWindow()
myQMainWindow.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

---

If you want to modify your PyQt code to use the PySide naming scheme, that can be done using a simple definition:

```
QtCore.Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal
QtCore.Slot = QtCore.pyqtSlot
```

[Reference this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt)

---

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

`signal_records` falls out of scope as soon as `main.__init__()` returns and is garbage collected. You need to make it a member of `main` so that it persists for the lifetime of the class.

```
self.signal_records = Records.Records()
self.signal_records.atSig.connect(self.showNewData)
```

Alternatively, you could assign `main` as the parent of `signal_records`

```
signal_records = Records.Records(self)
```

Both methods ensure a reference to `signal_records` sticks around.

Comment: I don't think so. It not clear by self. It clear by parent of class has been deleted only.

Comment: This is what is happening in @user3077627's code. The reason your code works is because you assign a parent to the dialog which keeps a reference hanging around. In the case of PyQt/Pyside this has the same effect as making it a class member.